# Pandas data frame and SQL Query Join

Tags: mysql, pandas, join

I have a pandas data frame with `ID` as a primary key and I want to join this with an SQL Query while. SQL data base is so big, I can't do `SELECT *` and then `join`, it will crash.

Example: pandas data frame df contains column name `ID` and it contains values such as `id1abc, id2abc, id3abc` and so on. And SQL data base WORK.EMP_TABLE contains column `ID` and the values are `id1abc, id2abc, id3abc` and so on up to billions. How do i write a SQL query code or similar to get only matching records of a pandas data frame from the SQL table.

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd

## Assuming you have a connection object (`engine`) to your database

df.to_sql('temp_df', engine, index=False, if_exists='replace')

sql_query = """
SELECT df.*, et.*
FROM temp_df df
INNER JOIN WORK.EMP_TABLE et ON df.ID = et.ID;
"""

result_df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, engine)
engine.execute("DROP TABLE temp_df")  # Clean up the temporary table

Comment: Hi Thanks for getting back. Unfortunately the above is not working because of the Engine, we connect to our db using below sample code.

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('oracle-db', 1234, service_name = 'db_prod')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=my_username, password=my_password, dsn=dsn_tns)